# Logging user activities in Nexus, how?

Tags: nexus, sonatype

we'd like to log user activities in Nexus like:

1. user log in
2. user log out
3. artifact downloaded by user
4. artifact uploaded by user

How should the loggers be configured in Nexus to be able to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on a reasonably recent version of Nexus check the sonatype-work/nexus/logs/request.log, the user ID associated with all requests is printed in the third column.